# Is the 'original-awk' Debian package sufficient to verify the POSIX compatibility of an AWK script?

Tags: awk, posix

In this case I'm referring to `original-awk/stable,now 2012-12-20-6`.

In other words, are there any significant versions of *nix/BSD that might be running a version of AWK not accurately described by The Awk Programming Language (Aho, Weinberger, Kernighan)?

Comment: While you can verify that a script is POSIX compliant (mainly by reading the documentation for it), you can't verify that a script will work the same way in all POSIX awks if that's what your goal is because there are behaviors that are undefined by POSIX and so each implementation has to decide how to implement them. For example you can have an awk where `END{print}` outputs the last record read and another where `END{print}` outputs a null string and both are POSIX compliant since the value of `$0` in END is undefined but a script written for one won't behave the same when run in the other.

Comment: @EdMorton I wrote this question after I saw you make the claim that a snippet of your code would run exactly the same on all awks/unixes. How do you verify that? Is it just experience with a particular construct, or do you have a process for testing portability?

Comment: It's just knowing what is and what isn't defined by POSIX. Last year I asked the gawk providers to update gawk to provide warnings about everything non-POSIX whenever the `--lint` flag was used (see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2018-08/msg00006.html) and they've made improvements but there's still some others that still go unreported. Let me see if I can find the list I sent the gawk guys and then I'll post that here just as an FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be making several assumptions and asking several questions here.

**Does https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk implement exactly the POSIX specification and nothing else?**

I think the answer is no; there will be behaviors which are not described by POSIX, either because the specification is not detailed enough, or because the author implemented a feature which is not specified by the standard.

Notice also that `FIXES` describes a POSIX compatibility enhancement from as recently as earlier this year; presumably it was not the last one, even if the maintainer's intent may well be to adhere to POSIX.

POSIX is also a moving target. Though progress is slow, it gets updates.

**Does the 1988 book correspond to the 2019 POSIX standard?**

No, obviously not. They are two entirely distinct types of documents for wildly different purposes.

Did the original Awk implementation influence POSIX? Quite obviously. Did they take it and declare it as the one true reference implementation? Clearly not. For one thing, that would definitely have risked their mission - you can't favor any particular implementation at the expense of others if you want your interoperability committee's work to succeed in the field.

**Is POSIX a reasonable baseline for compatibility?**

It is eventually supposed to be, but there will always be scenarios where, say, small memory footprint is more important than actual interoperability, let alone a rubber stamp which costs time and money to obtain.

(Don't get me wrong, there are many situations where I and many others will pay for that certification, or take our money elsewhere if it's missing. I'm merely pointing out that there are also many situations where we won't care.)

You seem to be approaching this from the wrong angle, anyway. Unless you know more about the POSIX specification than the Awk author, chances are there are interoperability bugs in your script which will not disappear if your script runs under an Awk implementation which perfectly implements the relevant POSIX spec. Your test suite should test for specific behaviors, not trust that the spec and its implementation are bug-free from your perspective.

**Is `bwk` Awk a minimal baseline for compatibility?**

No, I think you will find that there are several other Awk implementations which in some cases are more primitive.

My memory is hazy, but I have recollections of cases where Awk was ahead of the pack (something with Unicode support maybe?) and cases where `mawk`, not `nawk`, was the one which couldn't behave.

In the background, somebody stage whispers *"Busybox."*

**Is a build from 2012 representative?**

Definitely not. As indicated above, `bwk`'s Awk is still actively supported and even developed.

Comment: Maybe see https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Awk which I stumbled across just now.

Comment: You're right, I oversimplified a complex topic. Thanks for breaking it down. Do you have a process for auditing portability?

Comment: Sorry, not really. As vaguely suggested earlier, have a test suite, and update it every time you have a bug or a regression. If it runs correctly and tests everything which needs to work in order for your script to run correctly, you know that it's portable to a particular platform if the test suite passes there. The obvious corollary is to regularly run regression tests on all platforms you need to support.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer but per [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878005/is-the-original-awk-debian-package-sufficient-to-verify-the-posix-compatibilit?noredirect=1#comment98422893_55878005) here's the list of items undefined by POSIX and which I asked the gawk guys to provide a warning for when you call gawk with `--lint`:

[image]

Note that beyond POSIX compatibility there's other portability concerns. For example character classes like `[[:digit:]]` are portable to all POSIX awks but aren't supported by at least one common awk, the poorly named `nawk` (it was new when it came out in the mid-80s in comparison with the mid-70s old awk - now, not so much!).

Also the above table doesn't include functionality clearly documented as gawk extensions and disabled by `--posix` such as `gensub()` nor anything that `--lint` already reported - the intent of me creating that was to get the "missing" undefined behavior included in the `--lint` output.